# Bootstrap modal causes underlying content to align left

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Our Bootstrap modal causes the underlying content to align left. This appears to be an unusual issue on some Macbooks on Chrome and not others (my co-workers computer but not mine which has same specs).

Below is what it looks like. Notice the "Summary, Interests, Experience..." menu  and the graphs are pushed far left whereas they should be centered on the page.

I'm an experienced dev, but frankly I'm confused as it doesn't appear user-agent specific. We are using Bootstrap 4 Modals.

[image]

Comment: when you hide the modal does it go back?

Comment: @www.eugenehp.tk can't remember as I've only seen it on other people's screens but I think it does go back to normal. What would you think in either case?

Comment: probably a root container that you use in your page has different settings, so you might want to check what CSS parameters are being changed when you open a modal, and investigate the trigger of that event in your inspector.

Comment: "has different settings". Has different settings than what?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in Bootstrap(BS) 3.x.x.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9855

Looking at this I can only assume that it has been fixed for BS 3.x.x but they have not managed to cover this in BS4.

The trick to fix this, is to show the scrollbar for modal over the scrollbar of the html contents.

Please try using the below fix and let me know if it works.

```
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

/* when the model opens */
.modal-open {
 overflow: auto; 
}
```

`modal-open` is a class that is assigned to the body when the modal is opened.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this today!